# AngularJS $http service never calls the error handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-service

I have this code:

```
$http
.post('/api/login', $scope.user)
.success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  // code
})
.error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
  // code
});
```

It works, but even though the server returns an exception (status 500) or a bad request (400) or an unauthorized request (401) it still calls the success handler.

This is an example response from the server (my server is ASP.NET Web API 2):

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcRG9jdW1lbnRzXFRpbWVUYWJsZVxqYW4tMjAxNFwxMVxUaW1lVGFibGVcVGltZVRhYmxlXGFwaVxsb2dpbg==?=
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Sun, 23 Feb 2014 10:56:09 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: It may be a stupid answer but... Try only leave `data` in `.success`.

Comment: Looks strange, I see nothing wrong with you code, it is almost a copy'n'paste fra http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http. Have you tried with another URL?

Comment: It is a copy/paste from their site. I don't know what's wrong, every url in my app acts alike.. Some say that it has something to do with the content-length 0, could it be true? @RickiRunge

Comment: I wouldn't expect the content-lengh 0 - if that is really the case, then that would be an error in Angular. You could rule that out, if you create a URL that always return 400 and some content.

Comment: So it was partially my bad, I wrote an interceptor that will handle the response with `'responseError': function (response)` handler.. The problem is that after it runs and handles the error, the original code that made the request is being called with its success handler, why so? @RickiRunge

Comment: I would quess your intercepter then doesn't return a reject to the promise `$q.reject(reason)`

Comment: What was the solution, @NadavMiller?

Comment: Did you check what's there in 'status' parameter of 'success' handler? Is is 400 in it also or 200 by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure you are returning a rejected promise in your interceptor for the 'responseError' property. if you are simply returning the response or not implementing the 'responseError' then the success function will always run regardless of the status code.